# maria db galera cluster - wsrep provider is missing after install

Tags: mariadb, galera

I've installed MariaDB Galera cluster with .rmp files using this tutorial. 
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-installation-version-10121-via-rpms-on-centos-7/

and these packages

```
rpm -ev --nodeps mariadb-libs-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
rpm -ev --nodeps mariadb-5.5.56-2.el7.x86_64
rpm -ivh jemalloc-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh jemalloc-devel-3.6.0-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.3.10-centos73-x86_64-common.rpm MariaDB-10.3.10-centos73-x86_64-compat.rpm
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.3.10-centos73-x86_64-client.rpm
rpm -ivh galera-25.3.24-1.rhel7.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh MariaDB-10.3.10-centos73-x86_64-server.rpm
```

But it seems wsrep is completely missing.

When I run

show global status like 'wsrep_provider_version';

```
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| wsrep_provider_version  |       |
+-------------------------+-------+
```

Even library `/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so` is missing.

**Is some package missing or did I messed up instalation ?**

should I install some package from http://releases.galeracluster.com/mysql-wsrep-5.7/redhat/7/x86_64/ ? To add wsrep provider.

I searched available mariadDB rmps here https://mirror.vpsfree.cz/mariadb//mariadb-10.3.10/yum/rhel7-amd64/rpms/
But I didn't find anything which looks like wsrep.

PS: server is without access to internet and without any compatible repository ( this is reason why I'm using .rmp )

Comment: Let's see the config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was wsrep library `/usr/lib/libgalera_smm.so` is installed by default into different folder. 
Installation was ok, but the library is installed in

`/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so`